# How can I define bean if it has template interface

Tags: java, spring

I have interface

```
public interface ServiceImpl {
    public List<?> getAll();
}
```

and have bean class

```
public class MessageService implements ServiceImpl{
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public List<MessageItem> getAll() {
    List<MessageItem> lst = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from MessageItem c").list();
    return lst;
}
}
```

Bean is not created....

Bean defination

```
<bean id="messageService" class="ru.apusvao.phone.model.MessageService"/>
```

Exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [ru.apusvao.phone.model.MessageService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [ru.apusvao.phone.model.MessageService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: Your code is wrongly written

Comment: The exception does not relate to the code you have included, it's saying that something else is trying to autowire a reference to a `ru.apusvao.phone.model.MessageService` but that no instances of `ru.apusvao.phone.model.MessageService` exist in the application context.  Please include the code that is trying to autowire a reference to `ru.apusvao.phone.model.MessageService` and its associated bean definition.  Also please confirm whether or not all the beans are defined in a single file.

Comment: Naming an interface *ServiceImpl* does not make sense. The *Impl* suffix suggests it's an implementation which a interface isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MessageService implements ServiceImpl{
@Autowired
@Qualifier("transactionmanager")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public List<MessageItem> getAll() {
    List<MessageItem> lst = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from MessageItem c").list();
    return lst;
}
}

 <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    ...
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate transaction manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="MessageService">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this code does nothing to solve the problem and simply introduces a additional class.

Comment: But this is the correct way to add dependency ..http://javapapers.com/spring/dependency-injection-di-with-spring/   Check this

Comment: 'Autowired' can be applied to a constructor, setter or field any of which could be considered 'correct'.  The problem is Spring cannot find an instance of `ru.apusvao.phone.model.MessageService` to inject and hence throws the exception.

Comment: If you want to use at filed level then your bean tag should be on SessionFacory not on MessageService...But the problem is how you configure your factory in xml bean configuration

Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339973/autowiring-sessionbean-with-hibernate3-and-spring3